# Android: W/System.err: stat failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) :

Tags: java, android, file, exception, enoent

So this is my first time asking a question and I'm new to android. I've done a lot of searching for this error and it seems to be different form the open failed version of the exception. Does anyone know what this is and why this could be happening?

Some snipits of code:

```
        File dir = new File(context.getFilesDir() + "/modsntexs");
        dir.mkdirs();
        monsterFile = new File(dir, "/monster.jet");
        monsterFile.createNewFile();
        monsterTexFile = new File(dir, "/monster.png");
        monsterTexFile.createNewFile();
```

The error is:

```
W/System.err: stat failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) : /data/user/0/eu.kudan.ar/files/modsntexs/monster.jet
```

Thank you

Comment: Have you ensured that the file named in the error message is in the filepath?

Comment: Is there a way to do that via android studio? Sorry like I said I'm new to this @Nullarbor

Comment: Have you added required permissions in the manifest?

Comment: Yes I've added the permissions, both read and write. @K Neeraj Lal